# Level sets of Morse functions

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, morse-theory

Suppose we have a compact connected manifold $M$ of dimension $n$ and a Morse function $f$ on the manifold such that there are no critical points of index $n-1$ and of index $1$, how does one see that the non-empty level sets of this function are in fact connected?

Comment: consider $\mathbb R^2$\ point and project down it onto $x-axis$. It has no critical point, but levels sets are not connected. You might need to assume that its a proper Morse function.\

Comment: Thank you. I've edited the question with a stronger criterion than proper. But is the statement true for proper? If so do you happen to know an idea for the proof or some reference as to where I can find it?

Comment: You need to argue that if $M$ is a compact manifold with boundary, attaching a $k$-cell along the boundary can only change the number of connected components of $\partial M$ connected if $k =0$ or $1$, and in the first case it just increases the number of components. This is not hard, since the attaching map can only lie in more than one component if $k=1$. So if you end up connected and you have no $1$-cells, you must have been connected from the start: there should be a single $0$-cell.

Comment: So the assumption about there being no points of index n-1 is redundant? Also where does compactness feature in the argument? Wouldn’t attaching a 0- cell or 1-cell change the number of connected components of the boundary irrespective of whether it was compact or not?

Comment: The index $n-1$ assumption does seem redundant. If you aren't compact, you don't have a minimum, and thus you don't "start" somewhere; there's no inductive argument to be made. So my lemma about connectedness is fine, but to get your final desired result you need compactness. Similarly, when I say "end up connected", I assume you stop passing critical points eventually.

Comment: A function with critical points of index $n-1$ can have two distinct maxima with the same value. The level set at the maximum value is then disconnected. I think the confusion arises because of the difference between level sets and sublevel sets.

Comment: To see an example: take a three sphere and make a little dent at the bottom so there are two minima. This function has non-connected level sets, but it also has a critical point of index one. It does not have a critical point of index $2$. But $-f$ has the same level sets. However it has no critical point of index $1$.

Comment: Do you agree @MikeMiller?

Comment: @ThomasRot Yes, this was a silly mistake on my part. What I should have discussed above is the effect of adding a handle to the boundary, which is surgery, the following process: a $k$-handle attachment has the effect of deleting a $S^{k-1} \times D^{n-k}$ and gluing in an $D^{k-1} \times S^{n-k-1}$ in its place. It is clear that this operation can only affect connectedness if one of those is disconnected, which only happens if $k=1$ or $k=n-1$.